# Score system in Cocos2d project

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game where the user collects different types of objects and a label that has a value of 0 at the start. Every time the user collects an object (by touching it) it should make the score = current score + 1; I have tried with the following code but it crashes when I click on the object.

This is the code for my score label which puts a 0 on the screen:

```
score = 0;
scoreLabel1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Times New Roman" fontSize:33];
scoreLabel1.position = ccp(240, 160);
[self addChild:scoreLabel1 z:1];
```

And this is the void function which I call every time I touch an object:

```
- (void) addScore
{
    score = score + 1;
    [scoreLabel1 setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", score]];
}
```

And this is the actual part where I put the code for touching the object:

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self ccTouchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

for (Apple in self.appleArray)
{
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(Apple.boundingBox, location))
    {
        [self addScore]; 
        Apple.visible = NO;            
    }
}
```

Everything else works except for the score. Also is there a way to make the apple disappear instead of just making it invisible by apple.visible = false? because this way the apple is still there but not visible, I want to get rid of it.

Hope some one can help!

If you have any questions let me know.

Thanks.

This is where I draw the apples:

```
    -(id) init
    {
        // always call "super" init
        // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value

    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
    isTouchEnabled_ = YES;
    self.appleArray = [CCArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            Apple = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Apple4.png"];
            [self addChild:Apple];
            [appleArray addObject:Apple];
        }
     [Apple removeFromParentAndCleanup:true];
     [self scheduleUpdate];

     }
     return self;
}
```

And this is where the screen gets updated:

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
{
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    Apple = ((CCSprite *)[appleArray objectAtIndex:i]);
    if (Apple.position.y > -250) {
        Apple.position = ccp(Apple.position.x, Apple.position.y - (Apple.tag*dt));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: if you want to remove instead of make invisible, use the method `[ object removeFromParentAndCleanup: true ]`. Also for future, please do not ask two questions in one. Instead write two questions.

Comment: Hi dghendricks, thanks for your help. I tried [apple removeFromParentAndCleanup: true] and it doesnt seem to work. The apple will still stay there but invisible so when I keep pressing on it it will keep adding a point to the score label.

Comment: if you called `[apple removeFromParentAndCleanup: true] `, then there is no way that the apple stayed on the screen. Either you are seeing a different apple, you are not actually calling `[apple removeFromParentAndCleanup: true]`, or you are storing a reference to the apple somewhere else (an array?) and triggering a click from a different object based on the apple's position property regardless of whether is is actually on the screen or not.

Comment: Yes I called it and it did make the apple invisible but it still stays on the screen, you cant see it but its there when you click on it because it adds points to the score. the apples that fall are called from the appleArray which holds 5 apples. Im using a for loop to let apples fall on the screen 1 by 1

Comment: so it sounds like the last case is true. They are not actually on the screen or contained within any views or handling any click events, they are simply in an array that you have some other object (that handles the click events) cycle through to see if they are clicked on. You will need to remove them from that array as well to solve your issue.

Comment: Check above, I have added the code where I draw and update the screen and apples. Maybe you can understand this way better. appleArray is a CCArray. Let me know, thanks.

Comment: ehh, it looks like you aren't actually adding anything to the appleArray...

Comment: yeah sorry I forgot to copy this part in init [appleArray addObject:Apple];

Comment: and where is the part where you remove the apple?

Comment: at the top in CCTouchesBegan. but instead of Apple.visible = true; its [Apple removeFromParentAndCleanup: true]..

Comment: sooooo... You need to remove it from the array as well as from it's parent view. Add that and your code will be fixed.

Comment: Where exactly do I remove it from the appleArray? Im declaring it in the init and then adding one on the appleArray. But if I remove it, it wont show the apples on the screen. Check the updated code

Comment: no..... when you remove the apple from the view (because it has been clicked on, or whatever), you must also remove it from the array at this time as well. otherwise your game will still think it exists. oy good luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a couple of things here. In setScore, your format is broken and will cause a crash (%@ requires an NSObject*). Try:

```
[scoreLabel1 setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score]];
```

also, the syntax of your for loop is odd. Try

```
for (Apple *anyApple in self.appleArray)
{
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(anyApple.boundingBox, location))
    {
        if (anyApple.visible) {
            [self addScore]; 
            anyApple.visible = NO; 
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help. It wokrs now. Is there a way to make the apple dissapear from the screen instead of making the visible = NO; ? 
Because this way the apple is set to invisibile but it is still there on the screen, so if I keep pressing on it it will keep adding 1 to the score. I want the apple to be destroy'd once it is clicked on.

Comment: see edit. However, i dont know your app, and am not certain why you are keeping the object around.

Comment: do you mean [ object removeFromParentAndCleanup: true ] ? where object is apple? it doesnt work when i do this I dont want to keep the object arround. I want it to be removed

Answer (score 0):

```
score = score + 1;
[scoreLabel1 setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", score]];
```

Please read this: [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

**%@** - Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by `descriptionWithLocale:` if available, or description otherwise. Also works with `CFTypeRef` objects, returning the result of the `CFCopyDescription` function.

If your `score` is an object, you can't "increment" its value that way. If it's an int or a float, you are using wrong format specifier.

Comment: ooh ok I get it, thanks a lot for you help! I got that bit working now. Appreciated.